# segmentation fault in finding next greater element using stack

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have an array on which I iterate from right to left. You can see my implementation :

```
int arr[]{1,3,22,4,1,-3,3,7};
int n{sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)};
vector <int> v;
stack <int> s;
for(int i{n-1} ; i >=0 ; i--){
    if(s.empty()){
        v.push_back(-1);
    }
    else if(arr[i]<s.top()){
        v.push_back(s.top());
    }
    else {
        while(arr[i]>=s.top() && s.size()>0){
            s.pop();
        }
        if(s.empty()){
            v.push_back(-1);
        }
        else{
            v.push_back(s.top());
        }
    }
    s.push(arr[i]);
}
```

I am unable to debug, as the program crashes just after I start the debug session.

Comment: What do you think about the order of `&&` operands?

Comment: Yes, that was all the problem. Thanks Evg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic looks very convoluted. There is probably a much cleaner and expressive way to write what you mean.

The segfault is due to you checking if `s` is empty after you already look at the top
`while(arr[i]>=s.top() && s.size()>0)`
 you could try `while (!s.empty() && arr[i]>=s.top())`